# Open divs and close others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, css

So I have a section where I'd like to click on the image and have `.speaker-info` animate open by toggling class `.open` on `.speaker-container` to animate the height to reveal `.speaker-info` while toggling the class `.hover` for a hover state image. A `.fade` class also gets toggled on to `.speaker-info` to change the opacity. I got everything working fine if I click one image and close it with the same location, but when I open one and click another image everything closes, so I'll need two clicks to open the other, and the hover image states on for the previous image.

So I'd like to open one div and then if another image clicked, all close and the recent one opens.. I've been going around in circles trying to figure the best way to do this.. but I keep hitting a wall.

I'm basically triggering everything by toggling css classes to create the opening/closing and hovering.

Here's my code.

Also, I'm looking for opinions on how to make my code more nimble, and more efficient, sometimes I feel like I write waaay to much where I could do the same with a few lines less.

Thanks!

```
<section id="speakers">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class='speaker-container'>
    <div class="span3 offset1" id="{row_index}">
      <div class="speaker-img">
       <img src="{speaker_image}" alt="{speaker_name}" class="hover">
        <img src="{speaker_hover}" alt="{speaker_name}">
      </div>
        <h4>{speaker_name}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="speaker-info">
        <button class="close-speaker">Close</button>
        <h3>{speaker_name}{if speaker_title}, {speaker_title}{/if}</h3>
        <p>{speaker_bio}</p>
      </div>
   </div>             
  </div>
 </div>
</section> {!-- /End Speakers --}
```

Javascript codes

```
   $('.speaker-container').each(function(){

    var containerHeight = $(this).height(); 
    $('.speaker-info').css({ 'top' : containerHeight});

    });

      $('#speakers .span3').on('click', function(){
      var containerHeight = $(this).parent('.speaker-container').height();
      var h = $(this).next('.speaker-info').height();
      var totalHeight = containerHeight + h;

      $(this).find('.speaker-img').children().toggleClass('hover');

      $('#speakers .span3').not($(this).next('.speaker-info')).next('.speaker-info').removeClass('fade');

      if (!$('.speaker-info').hasClass('fade') && !$('.speaker-container').hasClass('open')) {

        $(this).closest('.speaker-container').css({'height' : totalHeight}).addClass('open');
        $(this).next('.speaker-info').addClass('fade');

      } else {

        $('.speaker-container').css({'height' : h}).removeClass('open');
        $(this).next('.speaker-info').toggleClass('fade');
        $('.speaker-info').removeClass('fade');  
      }

    });

    $('.close-speaker').on('click', function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('.speaker-info').height();
    $(this).closest('.speaker-container').css({'height' : container}).removeClass('open');
    $('.speaker-info').removeClass('fade');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use JQuery for that feature you want to do. Here's the link for your reference: [JQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). I hope it helps. Thanks!